# Uploaded links 404 error. Can't edit entries under super admin

Tags: 404, permissions

All the .doc and .pdfs (.jpg is fine) that we have uploaded to our site generate a 404 error and do not download. We have not changed anything on the back end of our site in quite some time and everything was functioning fine last week.

When I try to edit the file links on the backend, I keep running into this error: “An Error Was Encountered You are not authorized to access this page” and I am the superadmin.
If anyone has suggestions on how to resolve this I would appreciate it!

Comment: My permissions are enabled for me to upload

Comment: are you using htaccess and does it rewrite urls to jpg/pdf files as well?